# Available height for softkeys in landscape

Tags: android

For an InputMethodService in landscape Android automatically presents a text box that shows the text entered via the soft keys. How is it possible to get that text box height, so I can calculate the available screen height in landscape?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It works the other way around: I can use whatever portion of the screen height I want, then Android occupies the remaining space with the text box.

Comment: By the way, do you know what is softkey's standard size?